# HttpClient weird error with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, web-services, httpclient

So I have been using HttpClient for a while now for all my webservice restful api needs, today I got a client whose webservice is restful and works nicely with the explorer but when I consume it from my HttpClient the usual way i consume my services I get this error:

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in
>   your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

and I really have no idea why I am getting this error, or how to get around it, any simple advice on what I might be doing wrong is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
        <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("d770fadae897a53ffd5afb85bd9d9146");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://wsfotos.ml/wsreniec1/?dni=70183643&i=1";            </script>
            <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

I got that response using postman, do you guys think if has to do with that aes.js script?

Comment: Mabye it checks the Agent ID? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing It is also possible it is designed to interact with some specific parts of JavaScript, so it does not work in a general context.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, and is there any chance to workaround this? I mean I want to use the json response of the client.

Comment: If it is user Agent ID, you can spoof that simply. But honestly the exception sounds more like it tries to use some part of JavaScript in some way and fails.

Comment: tried spoofing the agent id like this "client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36");" still no luck, might be the error with javascript as you pointed... damn i feel useles hahahaha

Comment: This is definitely a very unusual issue. I can not even think of a way in wich a WebAPI might require JavaScript. Or call JavaScript for that mater. Unfortunately I am not that much of an Expert on WebAPI's.

Comment: Found the whole error, and I dont even think it has to do with javascript, weird that HttpClient points you that way. I used fiddler to see what was happening and I found out the difference between calling it from my browser and from my httpclient was a cookie, set up a cookie header with the same cookie I got from fiddler and voilá! It is working as it should be working now.

Comment: Of course, that makes some sense. Maybe the Cookie was supposed to be set by JavaScript *somehow*? So the cookie not being there was interpreted as "JavaScript must not be there" when someone decided wich error message to return? It did not occur to me that it might just be a faulty default Exception Message.